Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/tapadoo/android/alerter/2.0.4/alerter-2.0.4.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
I am experiencing issues with resolving dependencies like com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0 and com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.4. It seems that JCenter has become a permanent redirect to Maven Central, but these dependencies are not available on Maven Central or JitPack. I also receive '401 Unauthorized' errors for some dependencies. How should I handle these issues, and is there a workaround for JCenter deprecation?"enter image description here

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

If Jcenter() or mavenCentral() nothing works for you then simply add under repositories in setting.gradle or build.gradle(Project)
    maven { url '(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)' }
 maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google' }
 maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter' }


Quoting from JCenter's sunset announcement

What should a user do if a package they need is not available in Maven
Central? If a specific package version you need is not available on
Maven Central, you have the following options:

Contact the package owner and request that they make it available on
Maven Central
Check for a more recent version of the package on Maven Central
Remove your dependency on the package
Copy the package to your organization’s internal repository

If you are a JFrog user, and none
of these options work for you, please reach out to support@jfrog.com.

